div height change on scroll
Is there a solution to achieve the effect of changing div size on scroll?
I want to have effect like this: https://angular-f6srve.stackblitz.io
I am using angular hostListener to catch scroll events and I apply necessary changes into div. Unfortunately, sometimes I see some delays / stuck. The div height change not always reflect the actual position of scrollbar and this difference is visible, the change is not smooth.
This situation is more visible when the angular application is more complex than this one in example. Do you know, guys some lib which works better, or could it be achieved using CSS?

May be you can archieve this by using css :   position: sticky;
This is a example i found in internet:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/sticky-css?file=style.css


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .header {
        background: teal;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
      }

      .item {
        height: 3rem;
        background: #efefef;
      }

      .section {
        height: 100vh;
        background: #efefef;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="header">header</div>

    <div class="section">asdf</div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>




Please do not post external links, as the link might be dead one day.

@Raptor I have edited the post to include the HTML content directly instead of relying on an external link.  Thank you for the reminder.

I think it's not the same case. In your example, the div has a static height. In my, it's always growing on scroll.
